# high spin atoms SU(2) representation

Tags: group-theory, group-representations, lie-algebra, atomic-physics

I am very confused that some atoms called high spin or magnetic atoms have spin level more than $\frac{1}{2}$ but are still said to have $SU(2)$ symmetry.

Why not $SU(N)$?

Comment: You can apply a rotation to many objects, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group. If I understand your confusion correctly, [this thread](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19323/groups-acting-on-physics-a-clarification-on-electrons-and-spin) might clarify the situation, if you take into account that you have countable infinite representations of the rotation group.

Comment: This is because the group $SU(2)$ is essentially the same as the rotation group $SO(3)$ (more specifically, $SU(2)$ is a _double cover_ of $SO(3)$, with two $SU(2)$ matrices, differing by a sign, corresponding to each rotation). The assertion then says that high-spin atoms have rotational symmetry, with the proper treatment of signs (i.e. possibly accumulating a global $-1$ after a $2\pi$ rotation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$SU(2)$ has irreducible unitary representation of every spin $0,1/2,1,3/2,\dots$. Indeed, the spin $j$ is just the historical way of recording the dimension $1+2j$ of the representation space of an irreducible unitary representation.

On the other hand, the quantum numbers of $SU(N)$ (characterizing its irreducible unitary representations) are significantly more complicated than a single spin. For example, $SU(3)$ is physcally associated with flavor or color, not with spin.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, SU(2) can represent all spins or angular momentum. SU(2) symmetry is God given as long as it is real spin. But I want to point out that there could be **SU(N)** states, say, scattering of alkali earth atoms.